# Kafka Streams: Threads vs CPU cores

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

If the machine has 16 cores and if we define 6 threads in the config, would Kafka Streams utilize 6 cores OR would all the threads run on just a single core OR there is no control over the cores?

Comment: Are you only running ***one** instance* with many threads? http://aseigneurin.github.io/2016/10/07/kafka-streams-scaling-up-or-down.html

Comment: The question headline says "Task" but the question text ask about "threads" -- what is the question about?

Comment: Kafka Streams does nothing specific with regard to multi-threading, but relies on the operation system to assign threads to cores -- thus, by default it should use multiples cores  if you configure multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks, updated the subject, the above makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

## It is wrong to think this approach and multiple factors are involved here

If we define tasks as 6 , it means we have 6 partition for that topic which will be consumed parallelly by kafka consumer or connector.

If you have 16 cores and no other process running then chances are that , it will be executed as you expected.

This is not normal production scenario where we have multiple topics (having more than 1 partition ) which invalidated your theory.

You should have task based on consumer and machine should have only worker.
Once above condition is satisfied , we can perform performance test on that data

- How much time takes to process 50k record ?
- What is out expected time ?
- We can upgrade our system based on above basic parameters.